# How to distinguish AWS API errors in typescript?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I start stepfunction execution from typescript. I need to write different handlers for ThrottlingException and ExecutionLimitExceeded. How can I do this ?

```
new StepFunction.startExecution({}, (err, data) => { 
   if (err) {
      // how to distinguish ThrottlingException and ExecutionLimitExceeded
   } else {
      // process
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can distinguish based on the error name, for example:

```
    if (error.name === 'ThrottlingException') {
      // handle error
    }
```